# How was the Black Soulstone made?

Tags: diablo-iii

We hear Zoltan Kulle talk about how he "sacrificed" to make the Black Soulstone; is he referring to something besides his corporeal body?  It seems like it could be reminiscent of *Fullmetal Alchemist* where their magical stone (the Philosopher's Stone) was made via human sacrifice on a large scale.

In keeping with one of D3's themes, the forces that went into constructing it may be partially demonic in origin.  This hybrid of demon and angel could create something more powerful than either alone, but the "cost" may have been unpalatable to all but the amoral (viz. Kulle).

Answer (score 2):

It was said how Kulle was not always...crazy.  He was chosen to be in charge of the soulstones by Tyrael while the three Prime Evils were hunted.  After being around them that long, it apparently wasn't easy and he pretty much lost his humanity.  To try and get it back, he decided he was going to make a better soulstone (Black).  Once the Horadrim found out what he was doing, they dismembered him.  So in answer to your question regarding his "sacrifice", he might be referring to the fact that he not only gave his life to make the soulstone, but his spirit and sanity as well.  I haven't seen anything directly related to how he actually created it.